# Рисунок на javascript внутри таблицы

Tags: javascript

Доброго всем времени суток, господа (уже пол года пытаюсь написать головоломку, описанную ниже)

**Представьте:** таблицу, размер ~ 1000х1000 (ну там, плюс минус, сами понимаете). Указываем точки 1 - `width:760 height:730;` 2 - `width:750 height:930;` 3 - `width:900 height:840;`

1. Можно ли как-то провести через все эти точки линии, и залить внутреннее пространство каким ни будь фоном? (скажем граница шириной X, цветом Y, и все что между ними залить фоном Z, с каким ни будь % прозрачности)
2. Еще хочется как-то сделать, что бы поверх или сзади (на выбор) таблицы отображалась эта фигура, т.е. выглядеть должно как таблица, с почти треугольником в углу

Можно ли это вообще сделать с помощью JS, без изображений как таковых?

Comment: canvas или svg вам в помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ииии [раз](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-custom-shapes/), ииии [два](http://raphaeljs.com/), ииии [три](http://chikuyonok.ru/2011/08/optimize-with-canvas/). Читаем первое, второе используем по мере надобности, третье читаем, чтобы понять, как применить.

Comment: вообще думал меня с такой темой на 3 буквы пошлют ) ответ в точку, пойду изучать. спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

таблица -- это хтмл (статика)
динамический рисунок -- это жаваскрипт (динамика)
объединять их - задача неблагодарная.
но осуществимая.

например, я для рисования графиков на джаваскрипт использую вполне удачную jquery-библиотеку FLOT.
там отрисовка идет в обернутый див-контейнер, и в принципе после отрисовки вашей фигуры в этот же контейнер можно загнать собственно хтмл-код вашей таблицы.